# How can I check if the response header contains a certain string

Tags: go, request

I am trying to see if the `location` response header contains the string `queue`

Here is the structure:

```
if resp.StatusCode >= 200 && resp.StatusCode <= 399 {
        client.CheckRedirect = func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
            return errors.New("Redirect")
        }

        if location_headers_here_contains "queue" {
            fmt.Println("queue")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("Nope!")
        }

    }
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
if strings.Contains(resp.Header.Get("Location"),"queue") {
  fmt.Println("queue")
} else {
  fmt.Println("Nope!")
}
```

Comment: did not print it

Comment: all conditions were fine, but did not end up printing it

Comment: Print all the headers, see if it is really there

Comment: It didnt even print `Nope` is what I mean

Comment: My code doesn't print anything. You have to insert the if statement into your code.